# Python Pandas compare columns in a dataframe horizontally

Tags: python, sql, pandas, datatable, compare

I have a table extracted from SQL which looks like below. The background is that there are 2 systems that track the transactions. And sometimes, there are discrepancies between the items being captured by the 2 systems.

I am hoping to write a function/loop in python Pandas (or SQL directly) that can compare Items 1,2 and 3 from System A with Items 1,2,3 from System B, and return any rows that have NO common items.

[image]

Here is the expected output.

[image]

To explain the output.
In Transaction ID 1, because coffee appear in both systems, no need to return.
In Transaction ID 2, soup is no where in System A and this row should be returned.
In Transaction ID 5, System B failed to capture anything and this row should be returned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the dataframe, [`compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) each split and use the index of the comparison to get the correspondent rows from the original dataframe.

```
df1 = df[['SYS A Item 1', 'SYS A Item 3', 'SYS A Item 3']]
df2 = df[['SYS B Item 1', 'SYS B Item 3', 'SYS B Item 3']]

idx = df1.compare(df2).index

df.iloc[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make sets from the entries and then check if the sets don't share a single item:

```
a = df[['sys a item 1', 'sys a item 2', ...]].apply(set, axis=1).copy()  # <- columns of system a
b = df[['sys b item 1', 'sys b item 2', ...]].apply(set, axis=1).copy()  # <- columns of system b
# create mask where sys-a and sys-b don't share a single item
mask = [set(x).isdisjoint(y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# filter dataframe by using the mask
df[mask]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what isdisjoint and zip is doing here? thanks!

Comment: @user13617491 you might want to google for sets, isdisjoint and zip to get a better understanding. Sets are a datastructure like list, but only allow unique values. You can check if both sets dont have a shared item, that what isdisjoint does. zip combines two arrays so you can go through them at the same time.